# Mysql REORGANIZE algorithm

Tags: mysql, performance, partitioning, reorganize

I Have a question about partition merging on Mysql/MariaDB.

My table seem like this :

```sql
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(`mydate`))
(
PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-03-01')) ENGINE=InnoDB,
PARTITION p201903 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-04-01')) ENGINE=InnoDB,
PARTITION p201904 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-05-01')) ENGINE=InnoDB,
PARTITION p201905 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-06-01')) ENGINE=InnoDB,
PARTITION p201906 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-07-01')) ENGINE=InnoDB,
PARTITION p201907 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-08-01')) ENGINE=InnoDB,
PARTITION p201908 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-09-01')) ENGINE=InnoDB,
PARTITION p_future VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE=InnoDB
);
```

The `pfirst` partition is really huge (500M rows) and the partitioning is useful to get data from last months.

Monthly we merge the oldest partition `p201903` with `pfirst` and split `p_future` to create new partition (`p201909`) using these queries:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable REORGANIZE PARTITION p_first, p201903  INTO ( PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-04-01'));
```

and

```sql
ALTER TABLE EB_position REORGANIZE PARTITION p_future INTO ( PARTITION p201909 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-10-01')) ENGINE=InnoDB, PARTITION p_future VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE=InnoDB );
```

How mysql technically do that ? 
Is mysql creating new temp part and merge parts into it ?
Is mysql fill part with other part ? So, is it better to invert parts definition ? Like :

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable REORGANIZE PARTITION p201903, p_first INTO ( PARTITION p_first VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2019-04-01'));
```

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REORGANIZE` copies all the data from the source partition(s) into the destination partition(s).  Since it involves `p_first` and that partition is huge, it takes a long time, and locks the table.

From another point of view...  MySQL "plays it safe".  But creating the new partitions through a complete copy of the necessary data, if a crash occurs, the old partitioning is intact.  If, instead, it had tried to "merge" the partitions, a crash could leave the table corrupted.  Safety (and simplicity) is preferred over speed.

Instead of continually adding to that huge partition, add to the second partition.  Or, think of it as building yearly partitions.  More specifically, leave `p_first` alone and add `p201904` to `p201903`.  Next month, add `p201905` to `p201903`.  At the end of the year, switch to a 'better' naming convention of `p2020` to collect the 12 months of the year 2020.  Etc.

After a decade, you will have about 18 partitions; this is not "bad", and you will see very little difference in normal operations due to 18 instead of 8 partitions.

> ... useful to get data from last months.

Only if you are scanning the entire month's partition.  Let me see the query that benefits from your monthly partitioning.  In almost every case, partitioning does not provide performance benefits.  It is likely to require changes to the indexes to make a non-partitioned table work as fast, or faster, than a partitioned one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Partition is very useful by month because indexes size is 2x greater than data. There is lot of columns on this table and queries on it are really diversified. 
Some query on partitioned can be executed on 5 mins but without it, it's 9 hours.

Comment: So, if i understand your answer, my second alter query must be quicker than first ?

Comment: @user634062 - "9 hours" -- sounds like a missing composite index.  Even "5 minutes" is worth looking at.

Comment: @user634062 - The `ALTER` to make a new month should be done just _before_ you need it.  That is, `p_future` should remain empty (unless there is a hiccup and creating the new partition fails).

Comment: My purpose is about sens of part selection `ALTER ... p_first, p20190`  instead of `ALTER ...p20190,p_first `

Comment: Based on http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint, I'm on #3 use case.